# Calling a 'remove course' Public Function, issue with stored procedure parameters in visual studio

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I'm having a problem executing a SQL Server `deleterecord` stored procedure.

The stored procedure parameter my code is looking for is `@modifiedby`. I provide that but when I hit the 'actionon click' button it does nothing.

See code below

`Course` table:

```
Course_ID   int Unchecked
Course_Desc varchar(500)    Checked
Type_Code   varchar(50) Checked
Course_Name varchar(200)    Unchecked
Course_Number   int Unchecked
Category_ID int Checked
Credit_Hours    int Checked
Created_Date    datetime    Unchecked
Created_By  varchar(100)    Unchecked
Last_Mod_Date   datetime    Unchecked
Last_Mod_By varchar(100)    Unchecked
Client_ID   int Unchecked
Date_Deleted    datetime    Checked
Owner_User_ID   int Checked
SubmittedByUser_ID  int Checked
```

Stored procedure in SQL Server:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_DeleteCourse]
    (@CourseID AS INT,
     @ModifiedBy AS VARCHAR(50),
     @ReturnMsg AS VARCHAR(500) OUTPUT) 
AS
    --flag on the delete
    SET @ReturnMsg = ''

    UPDATE Dat_Courses
    SET Date_Deleted = GETDATE(),
        Last_Mod_By = @ModifiedBy,
        Type_Code = Type_Code
    WHERE Course_ID = @CourseID

    DECLARE @Err AS VARCHAR(100)

    BEGIN
        SET @Err = ''

        DELETE FROM Dat_Courses 
        WHERE Course_ID = @CourseID

        SELECT @Err
    END
```

VB public function to call stored procedure:

```
Public Function RemoveCourse(ByVal CourseID As Integer, _
                             ByVal ModifiedBy As String) As String

    Dim courseTicket As CourseTicket
    ' call stored procedure
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection(ConnectionString.GetComluxConnectionString())
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(cmdText:="sp_DeleteCourse", connection:=conn)
    Dim rVal As String = ""

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 60

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@CourseID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = courseTicket.CourseID
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ModifiedBy", SqlDbType.Int).Value = courseTicket.SubmittedByUserID
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReturnMsg", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = courseTicket.CourseName

    conn.Close()
    conn.Dispose()
    cmd.Dispose()
    conn = Nothing
    cmd = Nothing
    ' return single row
    Return rVal
End Function
```

Comment: This is SQL Server you are using, not MySql.

Comment: It does not work because you never `Open()` the connection and never `Execute()` the command.

Comment: Your procedure doesn't work - so stop VB coding and work on the procedure. And start over with the procedure. Does it make any sense to update a specific row and then immediately delete it? And perhaps you should think about how to handle errors and communicate them to your application. Your procedure generates a resultset - what does your application do with that?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0):

Your stored procedure declaration

```
@ModifiedBy AS VARCHAR(50)
```

Your parameter

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ModifiedBy", SqlDbType.Int).Value = courseTicket.SubmittedByUserID
```

A varchar and an int are not compatible. Fix one or the other to match the actual column in the table. Actually, it is a little silly since you are going to delete it but I guess it might be in a log.

Comment: There are *way more* issues with the OP's code than that. *Some* of them have been highlighted in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49492661/11683).